# How can I have the value of each part of a variable alerted in one box instead of many?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
 const orgDates = $('span.ms-noWrap');
  orgDates.each((i, elem) => {
  let parts = $(elem).text().split('/');

  let dt = new Date(parts[2] ,parts[0] - 1, parts[1]).getTime();

  let diffdate = Math.floor((dt- new Date().getTime()) / (86400 * 1000));

  if(isNaN(diffdate) || dt > new Date().getTime() || $(elem).parents('tr').find('td:nth-child(9)').text() == 'Received' ){
    return 0;
  }

  if((diffdate+2) < 1) {
    if((diffdate+2) == 0) {
      diffdate = (diffdate+1) + ' day ago';
    }
    else {
      diffdate = (diffdate+1) + ' days ago';
    }
 }

  diffdate = diffdate.toString().slice(1);

  var message =  $(elem).parents('tr').find("a.ms-listlink").text() + ' ' + 
   $(elem).parents('tr').find("td:nth-child(4)").text() + ' was due ' + 
 diffdate;
  console.log(message);

 });
```

So my code works exactly like I need it to except for the alerts. Instead of back to back alerts I would like all of the to be multiple lines in a single alert. See fiddle below:

https://jsfiddle.net/rurounisena/3ov98dhq/

I am still learning so any advice would be helpful :)

Comment: Like this? https://jsfiddle.net/ydxbgLf5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To achieve that, you have to keep a variable with the message **outside** of your loop, and just add a new part to it through the loop. And finally you can `alert` the message, but you should do that outside the `each` iteration method.

Regarding showing each message in separate row, you can use `\n` ("New line") for that.

Here is a working [**JSFIDDLE**](https://jsfiddle.net/wosLkn57/).

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `alert(str);` for each one, use:

```
var alertstr = '';

forloop {
  alertstr += newstr + '\n';
}
```

Then

```
alert(alertstr);
```